# Javascript - `onload` function called before loading?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've created an iframe using javascript:

```
fr=document.createElement('iframe');
fr.src="www.example.com";
fr.onload=doSomething();
document.body.appendChild(fr);
```

problem is the `onload` part seems to be running *before* the iframe loads - 
I get an error in the console (using chrome) about something undefined in the function (and it would be defined once the iframe loads), and when I check, it turns out the iframe was never even appended.

Comment: That’s because you are _calling_ the function, instead of just assigning the reference to it – `fr.onload=doSomething;` is what you want there.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you (and Travis. Can't accept his answer yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onload` expects a function reference to call

```
fr.onload=doSomething;
```

When you assign doSomething() to the onload event handler, its return is called (which is undefined) and that is the error you see. This is also the reason why `doSomething` appears to run immediately (because it executes during the assignment).

Comment: `onload` expects a "function reference".  That's the Javascript terminology for it.